# I changed my thinking it changed my life

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, syntactic-analysis

"I changed my thinking, it changed my life "

I have seen this sentence many times in social websites and each time I read it, as a nonnative English speaker, I feel something wrong with it! 
I'd say : I changed the way I think/my thoughts, it changed my life.

Do you think the usage of "**thinking**" is correct here? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which English  dictionaries have you looked up *thinking* in and what did you find?

Comment: @Clare I'm not criticizing dictionaries in here. I just need native speakers to explain this to me. Actually when I compare it to other possible verbs it makes no sense either. Check this one out : "I changed my walking it changed my speed" !!!

Comment: @user Clare is not suggesting you are criticising dictionaries. She is asking because there is a requirement here that you should present what research you yourself have done before asking here in order to find an answer to your question, and what it was about that research that left you unsatisfied. Otherwise people will probably just tell you the same things you had already found yourself. What is it you feel is wrong with the original? Why? What is lacking in dictionary definitions of the noun _thinking_? Please be specific, with examples and details—we are not mind readers, after all.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet answers will be more appreciated than arguments.

Comment: The question as it stands is **off topic**, and as such should not be answered. Please read the [help], and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The gerund in English has the form of the present participle in -ing. 
It is the most common form of the verb used as a noun ..." Linguapress.com

In your sentence, "thinking" functions as a noun and its meaning is clear:
"the process of using one's mind to consider or reason about something," Oxford Dictionary

There are other constructions that would get the point across, but that construction works fine.